# Beautiful Soup locating text after an <img> bracket

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am quite new at using beautifulsoup and I am having a little trouble extracting text after an  bracket.

```
<span content>"text"
    <img content src="/assets/images/photo.png">"Text I would like to grab"
    <span content class="classname">Text</span>
</span>
```

I am trying to extract the text after the photo but I cannot seem to grab it. Could anyone point me in the right direction

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_next` method by finding element `img` tag and extract text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
text1=soup.find("img").find_next(text=True).strip()
```

Output:

```
'"Text I would like to grab"'
```